# Why does my CSS work only beyond 546px (making divs be in center), even though the media queries are programmed to take care of that?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Here is the sample HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Title of Webpage</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page.css" />

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="header">
            <h1>CSS Troubleshoot</h1>
            <div id="home">
                <img onclick="location.href='index.html';" src="images/home-outline.png" alt="press to go to home page" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="game" style="width: 520px; height: 400px;">
    
                 </div>
               
                <div class="webcam">
                <video width="400" height="300" autoplay id="movie" style="position: fixed;"></video>
                <div class="headpos">
                    <p id="directionHead"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <h2>How to Play</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>
                         Instruction Text.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <h3>Have Fun!</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
        <div class="buttonGroup">
            <button class="btn" id="howBtn">How to Play</button>
            <button class="btn" id="snakeBtn">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn" id="breakoutBtn">Button 2</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

            var btn = document.getElementById("howBtn");

            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            btn.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "block";
            };

            span.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            };

            window.onclick = function (event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
#howBtn {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
#breakoutBtn {
    margin-right: 10%;
}
.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.75em 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border: 0px;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: red;
    color: black;
}

.modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1; 
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
}

.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {
        top: -300px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {
        top: -300px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}

.modal-body {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}
video {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
.headpos {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 930px) and (min-height: 550px) {
     html {
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    #home {
        filter: invert(1);
        min-width: 48px;
        min-height: 48px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 5px;
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .header {
        min-height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
    }
    .container {
        margin-top: 5%;
        height: 60%;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #game,
    .webcam {
        border: 5px solid red;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    }

    #game {
        margin-right: 2%;
        max-width: 520px;
        max-height: 400px;
    }
    .webcam {
        min-width: 400px;
        min-height: 330px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .buttonGroup {
        margin-top: 7%;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 929px) {
    html {
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    #home {
        filter: invert(1);
        min-width: 48px;
        min-height: 48px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 5px;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .header {
        min-height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
    }
    .container {
        margin-top: 2%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #game,
    .webcam {
        border: 5px solid black;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px red;
        clear: both;
        transform: scale(0.6);
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #game{
        display: block;
        width: 520px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    .webcam {
        width: 400px;
        height: 330px;
        display: block;
    }
    .buttonGroup {
        top: 7%;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-between;
        clear: both;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
    }
}
```

As soon as you get to below ~546px, the div with the id `#game` just completely stops being in the center, and the same occurs for the `#webcam` div underneath it. I've tried searching it up on Google, but no results that I'm looking for come up. I'm assuming this is probably because I can't quite word it right, so I'm hoping one of you folks may be able to help me. [Click here for the codepen link](https://codepen.io/mdsiam8/full/dyMJXjZ), or alternatively, copy and paste this into the search bar: https://codepen.io/mdsiam8/full/dyMJXjZ.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simple reason: You define a fixed `width` of 520px for `#game`  in your media query for `@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 929px)`. (and `width: 400px` for 'webcam`). Fixed widths aren't responsive...

Comment: Oops, I apologize. Now that I read the title and the post, I realize that I worded it wrongly and it sounds like I am talking about making the div scale responsively to the size of the display. What I really meant by responsive was that the divs should always be in the center, but after the ~546px mark, they just completely ignore the css to stay in the center.

Comment: But a 520px wide DIV *cannot* be in the center of a page that is less than 520px wide (the missing ~26px probably being some margin or padding). Divs that are wider than the page will always be left-aligned (unless they have absolute or relatve position and are shifted by a negative `left` or `margin-left` setting)

Comment: I tried scaling it down further with transform:scale(.6), but it didn't fix the div centering issue. Shouldn't that been enough to fix it, since the 520px is becoming 60% of what it originally was, thereby smaller than the page?